# Data Loading with server-side rendering on @reach/router

Tags: reactjs

I started using [@reach/router](https://reach.tech/router) on a new react application and it still doesn't support data loading on server-side rendering (It's waiting for React Suspense).

> When React Suspense ships, these docs will be updated with some great of server rendering with data loading. Until then, you’ll need to come up with your own strategy.

I really liked the router and I'd like to know if anybody have an example on how I could implement it.

Thanks!